# how to generate database with maven CLI on spring MVC project

Tags: maven, spring-mvc

I am dealing with thos project: https://github.com/YiffyC/GKGestiBank/tree/master/ExempleBackend2

Until now, I have always generate the database with eclipse (graphically).

Now, I need to make the same action manually with maven. Which target should I use?

Comment: I am bit confused, what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to create the database and the tables